# Optimum filesystem structure for scripting language MVC applications

Tags: php, model-view-controller, filesystems

When I speak of scripting languages I am speaking of languages like Python, Perl, and (in my case) PHP. After using CodeIgniter, Zend, and lots of other fun MVC systems it seems clear that one thing one one seems to agree on is the folder structure (alongWithOTher things_like_that). This is really causing a problem for me because I can't find any good documentation on the benefits of different structure designs. Most people just recommend one because *that is what they use* without regard for improvements in design.

One of the things I hope we can all agree on is that checking the file system for existing files when autoloading classes is very bad practice. Our classes should not be in one of 5 possible locations causing a barrage of file_exists() checks for each library we load.

So anyway, I am trying to collect directory structures that I can compare to find the best practices when planning for applications that:

1. Are OOP based which most likely means MVC
2. Are International in scope and support language files/translations
3. Are open to modules/plugins so that complete packages can be dropped into our codebase
4. Clearly define what is going on and where to look for given classes
5. Possible support for multiple sites running off the same structure (see /site directories below)

So here is what I have so far. Keep in mind that libs is just a term meaning your main library/class directory and may even contain models depending on the folder structure. Also, I excluded any type of static content (JS/CSS/images) as that stuff is really an after thought and not related to our serverside code - it may even be on another server! The same thing with caches, file uploads, lang, and all other generated content.

```
/controllers
/views
/models
/libs
/config
index.php
```

This kind of reminds me of the Zend framework which piles everything into a single libs folder (which also includes subfolders to keep things organized). Only works for a single site.

---

```
/libs
/site
    /controllers
    /views
    /models
    /config
index.php
```

This would a multi-site version of the above structure.

---

```
/libs
/functions
/site
    /controllers
    /models
    /views
    /config
/site2
    /controllers
    /models
    /views
    /config
/modules
    /user
        /controllers
        /models
        /views
index.php
```

This would be version that would allow multiple sites *and* drop in modules. The modules would be self contained MVC apps like a forum which would include business logic, CRUD, and views.

So does anyone have a *perfect structure* they could share or guide me in choosing a good extend-able design?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an overly complex example that does a good job of organizing everything - at the cost of clarity and simplicity.

[image]
<sub>(source: [gsdesign.ro](http://www.gsdesign.ro/blog/wp-content/uploads/2008/12/zend-framework-modular-dire.png))</sub>

Comment: Look like the Zend Framework skeleton structure, i'm pretty happy with it too ! It allows to easily extends the structure to your needs.
To this, i like to add /etc dir where I store project scope, trees, db schema, etc...

Comment: Sadly, the answer with the most votes is my own. So I'm no better off than before... Whats with that? ;P

Answer (score 3):

Not to specifically recommend [symfony](http://www.symfony-project.org), but rather it's approach, which I think is [pretty good](http://www.symfony-project.org/book/1_2/02-Exploring-Symfony-s-Code#chapter_02_code_organization) (but not "perfect")

Allows for:

- I18N
- Multiple environments (dev, qa, prod, etc)
- External libraries
- Plugins
- Multiple sites (domains or otherwise)
- Batch processing (command-line tasks)
- Unit tests
- Documentation
- Logging
- Caching

Also, among symfony's ups and downs, one thing I think it does pretty well is caching.  And I don't mean [template/view caching](http://www.symfony-project.org/book/1_2/12-Caching) - I mean [compilation-like caching](http://www.symfony-project.org/book/1_2/05-Configuring-Symfony#chapter_05_the_configuration_cache).

When a project is executed the first time, symfony builds a master file of library classes which, upon successive hits to the application, not only removes dozens or even hundreds of stat calls per request, but performs other optimizations like the removal of comments.

It also caches configuration data and autoload information, all of which can be tweaked to suit your needs.

Comment: That last thing you mentioned sounds like a complete waste of effort on symfony's part. Why not just use a opcode caching system like APC, XCache, or eAccelerator?

Comment: Yes, thanks for sharing the symfony style. From my brief look, one thing that it doesn't do is share modules. Each site, then each application (frontend/backend) has it's own modules directory which means that you have to make as many copies of each module as you plan on using. So rather than a global idea of modules - it becomes just a single local library idea.

Answer (score 1):

We use a structure similar to your last "multi-site" option for a mutli-site forum engine we built in house and it works out really well. You can always copy modules over if you need, and it also allows for the possibility of Site A customizing their module a little without affecting Site B.

When you get into practical applications of this, you're talking about completely separate teams, maybe even businesses using those two sites, a little division is not the worst thing. We also have a shared modules folder, but if you name a file the same thing in the Site's modules folder, it uses that version instead. Using that and __autoload (assuming PHP), then the Site devs don't really have to worry about where the module is located to use it.

Comment: That is a good point. The fact that you have two different sites means (if they are large) that you probably have little related between them. Especially if this is a framework which indicates custom code. 

However, taking from the drupal/wordpress approach we see that many times 1,000's of sites can all use the same plugins/modules while changing nothing more than the CSS. This is what I am hoping to attain in a design.

Comment: "We also have a shared modules folder, but if you name a file the same thing in the Site's modules folder, it uses that version instead." That is how I would imagine this working - except that if a module is only used for one site then it might as well be unpacked into the controller/model/views that make it up and put in their proper locations.